# How to auto-generate order XML - Magento 2

Tags: xml, magento2

What is the best way to generate an order XML automatically whenever a new order is created in magento 2? I'm going to import these datas to ERP using a webservice, so it needs to be in XML.

Something similar to this, but using magento 2: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/199581/generate-order-xml-for-erp-in-magento-1-9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to create a new Magento 2 module as shown earlier. If you want to react on events, you need to create a file etc/events.xml in you module directory. There you can define each event to listen on and set a listener model.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_save_after">
        <observer name="mymodule_sales_order_save_after" instance="MyCompany\MyModule\Observer\Observer" />
    </event>
</config>
```

If you want to get informed about each new order, you need to use sales_order_save_after event, which is fired right after creation of a new order in database. This is also the last step in Magento 2 checkout before redirecting a customer to a checkout success page.
you only need to create a execute() method. If you need things like factories or repositories, you can inject them as usual in __construct() method.

```
<?php namespace MyCompany\MyModule\Observer; 
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface; 

class Observer implements ObserverInterface { 

    protected $connector; public function __construct() { 
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) { 
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $customerId = $order->getCustomerId();

        if($customerId)
            #do something with order an customer
    }
}
```

I created a simple Model in module root directory called Observer/Observer.php. You can name it as you like both folder and model file. You only need to extend Magento 2 ObserverInterface class. There you need to implement execute() method, which gets an observer param as you may know from Magento 1. This observer model contains different information, based on used event. sales_order_save_after contans recently saved order object. You can use this order object to get or set information you need.